# ISNULL then Equal Another Column Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query I am trying to trouble shoot, it is using a full outer join with some subqueries. But I am getting Null for some of the columns title `TMS_ID`, I am trying to get these `NULL TMS_IDs` to populate with the value of another column `Employee_ID`. I am trying to get it to operate like

```
ISNULL(TMS_ID, Employee_ID) AS TMS_ID
```

Is this doable or is there another method I need to go about to accomplish this?

```
SELECT AC.REG_NR
    ,AC.DIS_NR
    ,AC.GEMSID
    ,AC.TMS_ID
    ,AC.EMP_NA
    ,AC.EMP_SEX_TYP_CD
    ,AC.EMP_EOC_GRP_TYP_CD
    ,AC.DIV_NR
    ,AC.CTR_NR
    ,AC.JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE
    ,AC.JOB_GRP_CD
    ,AC.Job_Function
    ,AC.Job_Group
    ,AC.Meeting_Readiness_Rating
    ,AC.Manager_Readiness_Rating
    ,CD.Employee_ID
    ,CD.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Expr1
    ,CD.Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Expr2
    ,CD.Meeting_End_Date
    ,CD.EmployeeFeedback
    ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee1
    ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee2
    ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee3
    ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee4
    ,CD.DevelopmentForEmployee5
    ,CD.Justification
    ,CD.Changed
    ,CD.Notes
```

Comment: U need to use a Case statement. Can you put your current query?

Comment: Yes `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` should work here

Comment: What does your SQL statement look like?

Comment: I posted the SELECT statement

Comment: you posted half of a select statement

Comment: Your ISNULL statement appears to be correct. What are you getting, and what do you want to get that is different?

Comment: Tell us what goes wrong. Include the error message and/or incorrect results, as well as the full query, table schema, and expected results. Without these things, it's impossible to diagnose your problem.

Comment: Is there an actual issue you are having or are you just curious if there is a better way?  Coalesce is exactly what should be used here.  Not a case statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like

```
Case When  TMS_ID is null then Employee_ID
else TMS_ID end AS Calculated_TMS_ID
```

(OR)

```
COALESCE(TMS_ID,Employee_ID)
```

In the case of `coalesce` it will check if `TMS_ID` is null then use first `non-nullable` value; in which case it will use the value of `Employee_ID`

(OR)

```
ISNULL ( TMS_ID,Employee_ID )
```

But remember, `Employee_ID` must of same type as `TMS_ID` OR must be implicitly convertible to `TMS_ID`